# How to fix HP MSM760 Wi-Fi controller crash?

Tags: hp, wifi, server-crashes

The **HP MSM760 Wi-Fi Controller Team** composed by four **HP MSM760** is crashing and rebooting once a week at least. Each controller crashes at random if there is load on it (it only crashes at weekdays at shift time).

Is there any configuration to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After isolating the **Wi-Fi Controllers** and  **Access Points** in their own VLAN (with only these devices) the problem stopped.